# How is #+BEGIN_SRC sh :results drawer different to #+BEGIN_SRC sh

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, bash

While reading http://www.howardism.org/Technical/Emacs/literate-devops.html
I saw the author recommending

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results drawer
```

for "time-consuming and verbose" commands. (I do a lot of time consuming and verbose commands.)

I don't understand how it's better than

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh
```

I can expand/collopase the result either way.

Comment: Suggest you to use package https://github.com/astahlman/ob-async

Comment: I installed ob-async.   Emacs is not blocked now. Yay.