# How can I tail/stream output when evaluating org babel shell blocks?

Tags: org-babel, bash, async

I learnt about asynchronous execution of org babel shell code blocks,
thanks to:

[How is #+BEGIN_SRC sh :results drawer different to #+BEGIN_SRC sh](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37688/how-is-begin-src-sh-results-drawer-different-to-begin-src-sh?noredirect=1#comment59348_37688)

I want to know if it's possible to tail/stream the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question. Use

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/whacked/ob-shstream/master/ob-shstream.el